# loading CSS in Webpack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-4

I am trying to include the bootstrap css file in my app using Webpack (v4.5) using the instructions found on the offical website (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) but am getting the following error when running webpack.

`ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:3) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

I have tried all I can think of to get this working but am afraid I am probably missing something really obvious.

I import the css into my code using: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

And my webpack config looks like:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['react-app'] },
      },

    ],
  }
```

I have both `css-loader` and `style-loader` installed and am using the same webpack config that bootstrap displays in their docs.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Turns out I was being silly, I have both a server and browser config for webpack and was only putting the rules in one

Answer (score 0):

Do this first

`npm install --save-dev css-loader`

and then this

`npm install --save-dev style-loader`

After installing change your configuration like this

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
       fallback: "style-loader",
       use: [
           {
              loader: 'css-loader'
           },
           {
              loader: 'style-loader'
           }
        ]
    })
}
```

Comment: don't use minified file

Comment: I get the same error (except with change of file name) using the un minified version

Comment: Try closing and reopening the terminal or cmd prompt and than run the webpack

Comment: Annoyingly this didn't work, I tried deleting everything, closing everything down, restarting, reinstalling modules and running but still have the issue :(